# Command button and text box to add list formatting in a table

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox, commandbutton

I am trying to create a userform in which users type a title into a textbox and click a command button to add the reference. I want one text box and one command button to add a new item onto a separate line in an alpha list similar to:

a) Reference Title1
b) Reference Title2
c) Reference Title3

with each listed item on a new left aligned line.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
'Define the variable oVars
Set oVars = ActiveDocument.Variables
oVars("REF").Value = TextBox7.Value
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
Me.TextBox7 = Null
Me.TextBox7.SetFocus

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPNsz.png)

There is a screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish. The upper portion is the form i've created and the bottom is what the outcome should hopefully look like. I apologize for not being better able to explain myself

Comment: Thanks for telling us what you want. Now explain what you have tried and where you ran into trouble. Please include that in your question.

Comment: I'm new to coding what I have so far will let me put in one title and overwrite it when I click the command button.

Comment: Your question needs to contain a fuller explanation of the problem you are trying to solve by using a User Form. FYI, document variable fields cannot contain multiple paragraphs.

Comment: Is it possible to use a bookmark to get multiple paragraphs in a table cell?

Comment: @TimothyRylatt "Document variable fields" or "Document variables?" I suppose it does not matter since document variables can only contain a single paragraph.

Comment: A bookmark is a marked or designated location that can contain things. A bookmark can contain multiple paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this by adding a Rich Text Format content control to the document with 'Content control cannot be deleted' checked. If you add this in a paragraph formatted with a numbered style that will save you having to number the entries.

The routine below, which should be placed in a standard module (i.e. not the user form), will update the content adding the carriage return if it already contains text.

This method has the advantage that the text in the control can, if necessary, be directly edited without the user form, will update automatically, and can be repeatedly added to over the life of the document. Unlike bookmarks it cannot get deleted.

```
Sub AddTextToContentControl(workDoc As Document, ccTitle As String, textToAdd As String)
  Dim ctrl As ContentControl
  Set ctrl = GetContentControlByTitle(workDoc, ccTitle)
  If Not ctrl Is Nothing Then
    If ctrl.ShowingPlaceholderText Then
      'replace the placeholder text
      ctrl.Range.text = textToAdd
    Else
      'add to the existing text
      ctrl.Range.text = ctrl.Range.text & vbcr & textToAdd
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

You call this from your user form like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
   AddTextToContentControl ActiveDocument, "References", TextBox7.Value
   Me.TextBox7 = Null
   Me.TextBox7.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: That works great. I've been afraid of trying to implement content controls in VBA because all my experience with them comes from using Greg Maxey's plug-ins for using them directly on the document. Thank you.